# Problems with BroadcastReceiver and multiple proximity alerts

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, proximity

I realize this question already exists, but I am having trouble implementing the solutions.

I'm using these questions as guidlines:

[multiple proximity alert based on a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286108/multiple-proximity-alert-based-on-a-service)

[set 2 proximity alerts with the same broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298388/set-2-proximity-alerts-with-the-same-broadcast)

Where I register the receiver:

```
final String NEAR_YOU_INTENT = "neighborhood.crodgers.example.activities.PROXIMITY_ALERT";
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(NEAR_YOU_INTENT);
registerReceiver(new LocationReceiver(), filter);
```

Where the proximity alerts are added (Note: This is done in a service, hence the context grab):

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
final String NEAR_YOU_INTENT = "neighborhood.crodgers.example.activities.PROXIMITY_ALERT";
Context context = getApplication().getApplicationContext();

int requestCode = 12345; //Spaceballs, anyone? anyone?
for (String domain : domainNames)
{
    String[] itemNames = itemGetter();
    for (String item : itemNames)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> attributes = getAttributesForItem(domain, item);                    

        Intent intent = new Intent(NEAR_YOU_INTENT);
        intent.putExtra(ADDRESS, attributes.get(ADDRESS));
        intent.setAction(""+requestCode);
        PendingIntent proximity = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        manager.addProximityAlert(Double.parseDouble(attributes.get(LATITUDE)),
                                  Double.parseDouble(attributes.get(LONGITUDE)), 
                                  6000f, -1, proximity);

        requestCode++;
    }
}
```

Originally, I was getting notified for the first proximity alert added (using notifications from the receiver). After adding

```
intent.setAction(""+requestCode);
```

I also tried:

```
intent.setData(""+ requestCode)
```

(I have seen this recommended in several other places) I stopped getting notifications all together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is that you use setAction

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NEAR_YOU_INTENT);
intent.putExtra(ADDRESS, attributes.get(ADDRESS));
intent.setAction(""+requestCode); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

What you end up doing in that last line is changing the action from NEAR_YOUR_INTENT to whatever request code happens to be. IE, you are doing the equivalent of

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(NEAR_YOUR_INTENT);
    intent.setAction(""+requestCode); // THIS OVERWRITES OLD ACTION
```

### Extra Approach

I suspect what you really want to do is add the requestCode as an extra to the intent so that you can retrieve it in your receiver. Try using

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(NEAR_YOU_INTENT);
    intent.putExtra(ADDRESS, attributes.get(ADDRESS));
    intent.putExtra("RequestCode", requestCode);
```

### Data Approach

Alternatively, you could set the data to be your request code. IE, you could use

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(NEAR_YOU_INTENT);
    intent.putExtra(ADDRESS, attributes.get(ADDRESS));
    intent.setData("code://" + requestCode);
```

Then you would need to alter your receiver then so that it can accept the "code://" 
schema. To do this:

```
final String NEAR_YOU_INTENT = "neighborhood.crodgers.example.activities.PROXIMITY_ALERT";
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(NEAR_YOU_INTENT);
filter.addDataScheme("code");
registerReceiver(new LocationReceiver(), filter);
```

Then you could probably use some method to parse out the id from the data field when you get your intent. IMO, the extras approach is easier.